# Gmail login using curl in 2023

Tags: bash, curl, gmail

```
#!/bin/bash

email="email@gmail.com"
password="pass"
user_agent_file="/home/kali/Desktop/New Folder/user-agents.txt"
login_url="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier"

# Choose a random user agent from the user-agents.txt file
user_agent=$(shuf -n 1 "$user_agent_file")

# Send initial login request to get GALX and gxf cookies
init_response=$(curl -s -c cookies.txt -A "$user_agent" "$login_url")

# Extract GALX and gxf cookies from response
galx=$(grep -o 'GALX........' cookies.txt | sed 's/GALX=//')
gxf=$(grep -o 'gxf........' cookies.txt | sed 's/gxf=//')

# Extract the value of the "challenge" input field from the login page
challenge=$(echo "$init_response" | grep -o 'name="challenge" value="[^"]*' | sed 's/name="challenge" value="//')

# Send login request with email and password
login_response=$(curl -s -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -A "$user_agent" -d "challenge=$challenge&GALX=$galx&gxf=$gxf&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&service=mail&rm=false&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&TL=AM3QAYbJwlY_Lc9sTyvA1fNYFtC51RtWpkKjgOYd3qT1YvUM8TLMWfneF24-kdC_" -d "Email=$email" -d "Passwd=$password" "$login_url")

# Check if login was successful
if echo "$login_response" | grep -q "redirecting"; then
  echo "Login successful!"
elif echo "$login_response" | grep -q "Enter the second factor"; then
  echo "Two-factor authentication required."
elif echo "$login_response" | grep -q "Wrong password"; then
  echo "Invalid credentials."
elif echo "$login_response" | grep -q "unusual activity"; then
  echo "IP temporarily blocked."
else
  echo "Unknown error."
fi
```

This is my bash script to attempt and check login to gmail and everytime it is giving Unknown error when after entering wrong and right credential please look into it and tell modification to be made in this.

This is the user-agents.txt

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

i was expecting to get login successful or any other response but only getting Unknown error even after entering right credentials

Comment: This seems like an incredibly bad idea(tm). Just use a proper email client. The webpage can change any moment, breaking any script you might have working.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Just login, send mail... ?